# How can I write to replicated environments without impacting production?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Are there any methods (mirroring, snapshot replication, change tracking, etc...) available in SQL Server 2k8 which would allow me to replicate production data to several individual development databases *AND* allow separate data to be written to each of those dev db?

In other words: Once a full copy of data is replicated to a dev database, replication would be turned off so new data can then be written to the dev database without impacting the production database.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't simple backup/restore be enough? Just restore the production backup on all your dev servers and you should be fine. Btw. Sql server does not allow writes to replica servers as it would corrupt the data and it would no longer be able to figure out what should be updated.